# Was Geordi's VISOR ever spelled lower-case in "Star Trek: TNG" scripts?

Tags: props, star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

Reference materials for *Star Trek* spell the visual aide used by character Geordi LaForge as the acronym *VISOR*, instead of the word *visor*.  Was this also the case in the scripts for the television show?  Or were there some scripts (particularly early ones) where the prop is spelled in lower-case?

What I wonder is whether the producers took ideas from third-party merchandise and retroactively applied them to the television show, instead of coming up with the ideas themselves.  If the term appeared in lower-case early in the show's scripts, before it appeared in upper-case in third party merchandise, that becomes strong evidence that the producers ret-conned material from third-party sources.

Star *Wars* is notorious for this practice (Palpatine's name, Coruscant, kyber crystals, etc.).  Did the producers of Star *Trek* also do this?

Answer (score 5):

It's standard notation for scripts to capitalize important props, so I'm not sure that upper or lower case in the script has any special significance, even if a contrived acronym was created before or after the script was written.  [Longshank's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/102276/43022) seems to follow the script-writing convention that important plot and prop items are capitalized in scripts.

Generally, text in a screenplay’s actions or stage directions will be in ALL CAPS when something deserves special attention.

> Some common all caps examples:
>
> - The first time a character is introduced, his or her name should be in all caps. This is the one steadfast all caps rule.
> - Visual or special effects will often be in all caps.
> - Specific, important sounds that either have to be captured during filming or added in during post.
> - Any integral or specifically important props, wardrobe, or other details the first time it is mentioned.

[Source](https://screenwriting.io/what-does-it-mean-when-something-in-a-screenplay-is-written-in-all-caps/)

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that caps are used in places that we would now use italics.  That would make sense, given that TV and movies originated in an era when writers had typewriters that could do uppercase, but not italics.

Comment: I think CAPS are important here as they stand out more than italics do.  It's a clear instruction to the producers that certain props/effects/stage layouts are required as part of the plot.

Answer (score 3):

There are what appear to be shooting scripts for TNG episodes here: [Star Trek Minutiae](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/#thenextgeneration)

The script for season 1, episode 4 "[Code of Honor](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/104.txt)" contains the first mention of VISOR I could find, written as all capitals:

> ACT FOUR
>
> FADE IN:
>
> 47   INT. ENTERPRISE - GEORDI'S QUARTERS
>
> Geordi is standing alone in his room, his glasses on
>       a table. Without his **VISOR** his eyes are dead grey.
>       He holds a glowing 2-inch blue cube in his hand which
>       he moves up, down and across his face an inch or so away
>       from the skin. He is shaving. There is a CHIME from
>       his door.

However,

There is at least one instance where it is both upper and lowercase, in season 7's [The Descent](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/253.txt):

> DATA
>   Give me your **Visor**.
>
> GEORDI
>   (disbelieving)
>   Why?
>
> Data raises his Borg WEAPON threateningly.
>
> DATA
>   Give it to me or I will take it by
>   force.
>
> Geordi has no choice but to surrender it. He takes the
>   **VISOR** and EXITS the cell. The Borg Guard activates the
>   force-field, which FRITZES on and is visible for only
>   a moment. Data turns and regards his old friends with
>   a cold eye.

Comment: There had been an answer with another lowercase reference, but I cannot see that answer now.  Presumably, the answer was deleted and I do not have enough rep on this particular SE site to see deleted posts.  Would you mind adding that episode to your answer?  Thanks.

Comment: @DrSheldon The older answer refers to a transcription site as a source, the kind where people listen to the programs and type whatever they hear.